# How to access variables of a method in a different class in Java?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, scope

I have some variables in a class inside a method. How can I access these variables from a different class ?

Comment: Please give Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you mean local variables, there's no way you can access them from other methods, let alone other classes.

Comment: If the variables are local then you cant access them unless they are returned from the method. If the variables are instance members then you could provide a better for the same. But be careful because exposing the internals give another class a way to change the state from under the owner class's nose. Read more about copy constructor and its evil cousin cloning before you embark on this route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, variables declared inside a method have a scope limited to the method : they are not accessible outside of the method, even in the same class.

In that case, if you want to access them from outside, this means that their place is probably not as variables of the method, but as members of the class, ie "variables" declared as properties of the class, like this :

```
class Example {

   public int field; 

}
```

If you are referring to members, then whether you can access this field from outside the class depends on what you write in front of the field declaration :

- `public` : field will be accessible outside of the class
- `protected` : field will be accessible only in classes that extend this class
- `private` : field will be accessible only inside that class